# Slideshow pasarle imagenes dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un slideshow al cual actualemnte le paso imagenes escribiendo cada ruta de las imagenes en la etiqueta , lo que quiero hacer es cargar todas las imagenes de la carpeta que yo decida y las imagenes del slideshow cresca dinamicamente, es decir si yo de entrada tengo 5 imagenes pero agrego otras 5 a la carpeta entonces en el slideshow quiero que me muestra las 5 que habia y las 5 nuevas y asi sucesivamente.
Nota: las imagenes estaran en una carpeta compartida del servidor.
Esto lo encontre en la red con php pero no se como pasrle las imagenes al slideshow:

```
<?php
$directory="directorio/imagenes";
$dirint = dir($directory);
while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
{
    if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
        echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
    }
}
$dirint->close();
?>
```

Este es el diseño html del slideshow:

```
<div class="slider">
<ul>
    <li>
<img src="IMG_1662.JPG" alt="">
</li>
    <li>
<img src="IMG_1663.JPG" alt="">
</li>
    <li>
<img src="imgRB1.JPG" alt="">
</li>
    <li>
<img src="imgRB2.JPG" alt="">
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es algo extensa... puesto que para poder hacer todo aquello que deseas se requiere crear un código algo largo... mas o menos unas 100 lineas por el lado de PHP y otras 50 del lado de javascript para poder que sea dinamico en el html. Y de hecho no tendría ni idea de como podrías hacer que el servidor detecte nuevas imágenes y se autoejecute un script de php que se encargue de decirle al frontent que hay nuevas imagenes para actualizar en el front, puesto que si haces una peticion para saber esto es muy facil, pero sin hacer peticiones no tengo idea...

Comment: Ya que hacer que php detecte nuevas imágenes que tu arrastres a una carpeta sin que se le hayan hecho peticiones para saber esto (solamente con la acción de arrastrar) realmente o es imposible o muy complicado, creo que si o si requieres de una petición para poder que puedas realizar este comportamiento...

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no es tan complicado, con `glob()` puedes obtener todas las imágenes y solo debes modificar la parte donde creas el slider para leer y mostrar:

```
<div class="slider"><ul>
<?php
$images = glob("directorio/imagenes/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $img) {
    // Las imágenes ya incluyen el directorio
    echo "<li><img src=\"$img\" alt=""></li>\n";
}
?>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: me da el siguiente error 404 (Not Found) justo en lalinea del echo, en la consola esta es la ruta que muestra  http://localhost/presentacion/$img/

Comment: ahora me sale 403 Forbidden

Comment: las imagenes estan en la carpeta raiz

Comment: Inspecciona alguna de las etiquetas `img` y revisa la ruta, copia y pega aquí, junto con la ruta adecuada para poder decirte qué hacer.

Comment: asi es como tengo declarado  <ul>
          <?php
          $images = Glob("Presentacion/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
          foreach($images as $img) {
          echo  "<li><img src=\"$img\" alt=""></li>\n";
        }
          ?>
        </ul>

Comment: "Presentacion" se llama mi carpeta raiz @Triby

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como lo tienes ahora. Me parece que cambiaste las comillas dobles por sencillas.